# Find the smallest possible integer $k$ such that $8|7^{348}+2^{5605}+k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

$$
\text{Find the smallest possible integer } k \text{ such that } \\ 7^{348}+2^{5605} +k
\text{ which is divisible by } 8 \text{ given that }
$$

a≡b mod n⇒a^m≡b^m mod n

okay, I understand that $a \equiv b \text{ mod } n$ implies $n|(a-b)$, but how would I solve this problem? There are no congruencies to play with, any advice would be great..

Comment: Jeez, sorry, that was for another question i was going to ask but then I figured out how to do that problem, and closed the question tab. It looks like the content remains after re-opening the page

Comment: Something seems missing, did you mean $\,a\equiv b\,\Rightarrow\, a^m\equiv b^m\,?$

Comment: Yes, I think I forgot that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $7\equiv-1\mod8$, and $2^3\equiv0\mod8$.

Comment: thanks, ill see what i can come up with

Comment: hmmmmmmmmmmmmm, i just kept on pluggin numbers into a calculator and it looks like k=7, but I'm looking into why

Comment: Obviously, $2^{5605}$ is a multiple of $2^3=8$, so its remainder when divided by $8$ is $0$. As for $7^{348}$, its remainder when divided by $8$ is the same as that of $(-1)^{348}=1$, for the reasons mentioned above, since $348$ is an even number. So, in conclusion, what is the smallest *k* such that $1+0+k$ is a multiple of $8$? :-)

Comment: i see thanks lucian

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ 7,\,$ with $\ a,b \equiv 7,2,\,$

notice that  $\ \color{#0a0}{a\equiv -1}\ $ and, further, $\ \color{#c00}{b^3\equiv 1}\ $ hence

$\quad \color{#0a0}a^{\large 2n}\! + b^{\large j+3k}\equiv (\color{#0a0}{-1})^{\large 2n}\!+ b^{\large j} (\color{#c00}{b^3})^{\large k} \equiv 1+b^j\color{#c00}{(1)}^k\ $ by the Congruence Power Rule below.

---

**Congruence Sum Rule** $\rm\qquad\quad  A\equiv a,\quad B\equiv b\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#c0f}{A+B\,\equiv\, a+b}\ \ \ (mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\rm\ \ m\: |\: A\!-\!a,\ B\!-\!b\ \Rightarrow\ m\ |\ (A\!-\!a) + (B\!-\!b)\ =\ \color{#c0f}{A+B - (a+b)} $

**Congruence Product Rule** $\rm\quad\ A\equiv a,\ \ and \ \  B\equiv b\ \Rightarrow\ \color{blue}{AB\equiv ab}\ \ \ (mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\rm\ \ m\: |\: A\!-\!a,\ B\!-\!b\ \Rightarrow\ m\ |\ (A\!-\!a)\ B + a\ (B\!-\!b)\ =\ \color{blue}{AB - ab} $

**Congruence Power Rule** $\rm\qquad \color{}{A\equiv a}\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#c00}{A^n\equiv a^n}\ \  (mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\ $ It is true for $\rm\,n=1\,$ and $\rm\,A\equiv a,\ A^n\equiv a^n \Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{A^{n+1}\equiv a^{n+1}},\,$ by the Product Rule, so the result follows by induction on $\,n.$

**Polynomial Congruence Rule** $\ $ If $\,f(x)\,$ is polynomial with *integer* coefficients then  $\ A\equiv a\ \Rightarrow\ f(A)\equiv f(a)\,\pmod m.$

**Proof** $\ $ By induction on $\, n = $ degree $f.\,$ Clear if $\, n = 0.\,$ Else $\,f(x) = f(0) + x\,g(x)\,$ for $\,g(x)\,$ a polynomial with integer coefficients of degree $< n.\,$  By induction $\,g(A)\equiv g(a)\,$ so $\, A g(A)\equiv a g(a)\,$ by the Product Rule. Hence $\,f(A) = f(0)+Ag(A)\equiv f(0)+ag(a) = f(a)\,$ by the Sum Rule.

**Beware** $ $ that such rules need not hold true for other operations, e.g.
the exponential analog of above $\rm A^B\equiv a^b$ is not generally true (unless $\rm B = b,\,$ so it reduces to the Power Rule, so follows by inductively applying $\,\rm b\,$ times the Product Rule).

Comment: Hi Bill: Interesting,thanks for the help.

 I'm confused of what j,k are however.

Comment: @AA Above $\,j,k\,$ are any natural numbers. Choose them to fit your example. The point was to show that it works more generally than for the specific numbers in your example.

Comment: That leaves possible values of the first expression to be 3, 9. But it appears 7 is the answer;

Comment: @AA I cannot spot your error without seeing your work.